# VSCode pydevd: Sending message related to process being replaced timed-out after 5 seconds

Tags: visual-studio-code, ipynb

After updating VSCode, in my .ipynb notebook cells I'm getting:

```
940.62s - pydevd: Sending message related to process being replaced timed-out after 5 seconds
```

... on many cells. It seems to be cells that take > 5s to execute.

Somehow this update has broken something.

Is it killing the process after 5s?

This is annoying. Does anyone have any idea how to fix/revert?

Comment: related: https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/issues/1005